Rails 8 authenticated routes for rails g autentication
I am using Rails 8 and generated authentication with:
rails generate authentication
I want to restrict access to certain routes so they are not exposed to unauthenticated users.
In Devise, there's a constraint helper like this:
ruby
authenticated :user do
  # Allow all actions on subjects and nested students only for authenticated users
  resources :subjects do 
    resources :students
  end
end

Is there a built-in way to achieve this in Rails 8?
Is there a way to add that for the new generators?

There is no built-in way. You'd have to move authentication logic up into a middleware and use constraints helper in your routes:
# config/initializers/auth_middleware.rb

class UnauthorizedError < StandardError
end

class AuthMiddleware
  def initialize app
    @app = app
  end

  def call env
    request = ActionDispatch::Request.new(env)
    Current.session = Session.find_by(id: request.cookie_jar.signed[:session_id])

    @app.call(env)
  rescue UnauthorizedError
    [302, {Location: "/session/new"}, []]
  end
end

Rails.application.config.middleware.use AuthMiddleware

Since Current.session is already set you need to update Authentication concern:
# app/controllers/concerns/authentication.rb

def resume_session
  # Current.session = find_session_by_cookie
  Current.session
end

# def find_session_by_cookie
#   Session.find_by(id: cookies.signed[:session_id])
# end

and use it in your routes:
# config/routes.rb

class AuthenticatedUser
  def self.call
    # maybe call to Session.find_by should be here
  
    Current.session || raise(UnauthorizedError)
  end
end

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # 404 for unauthorized users
  constraints -> { Current.user } do
    # your routes
  end

  # redirect to login for unauthorized users
  constraints -> { Current.user || raise(UnauthorizedError) } do
    # your routes
  end

  # make it a bit more reusable
  constraints AuthenticatedUser do
    # your routes
  end
end

